# how to make a link in a markdown cell

Tags: hyperlink, markdown

I tried using the description but it comes out showing both the [] and the() and no words are linked... what am I doing wrong?

ex:[range_funtion](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/miscellionious-functions-of-python/)

Comment: when I post the question the link works but when I run the cell it just shows the url and does not link the words in []

Comment: Markdown doesn't support tables at all; they're an add-on provided by many, but not all, processors. Which Markdown processor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Which program are you utilizing to write your markdown in?

You may need to set the cell to use Markdown formatting.

The markdown syntax:

`[Google](https://www.google.com)`

Should output:

[Google](https://www.google.com)